# Парсинг html таблицы в c# без сторонних библиотек

Tags: c#, html

Добрый день(утро, вечер, ночь)! У меня возникла одна небольшая проблема: есть страница с таблицей (конкретно [эта](http://www.gks.ru/metod/XML/XML_plan_2017%20.htm)) и я ее должен превратить в datatable, что я и сделал, но в html-таблице присутствуют объединенные строки(rowspan), что смещает следующие, после строки с rowspan, элементы строки:

```
GetWebPageCode html = new GetWebPageCode();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var data = html.GetDataTable(html.GetCodeAsString("http://www.gks.ru/metod/XML/XML_plan_2017%20.htm"));
}
```

class.cs:

```
class GetWebPageCode
{
    public bool RemoveComment { get; set; }
    public string SplitTag { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Получает исходный код страницы <see cref="urlAddress"/>, автоматически убирает комментарии и оставляет только таблицу
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="urlAddress">http-страницы, которой надо получить исходный код</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetCodeAsString(string urlAddress)
    {
        string tag = "table";
        string data;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.Default);
            }
            data = OnlyTable(RemoveHTMLComments(readStream.ReadToEnd()),tag);
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            data = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        return data;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Формирует DataTable из предоставленного кода
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Код должен состоять только из кода таблицы (между тэгами table)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string input)
    {
        string[] str = Regex.Matches(input, @"\<tr.*?\</tr>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
        string[] cols = Regex.Matches(str[1], @"\<td.*?\</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
        Tag title = tdparse(Regex.Matches(str[0], @"\<td.*?\</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray()[0]);
        string tableName = GetValueOfTag(title.Value,"a");
        DataTable output = new DataTable(tableName);
        foreach (var col in cols)
        {
            output.Columns.Add(Regex.Replace(col, "<.*?>", String.Empty));
        }
        //List<List<Tag>> prev_cell = new List<List<Tag>>();
        for (int row = 3; row < str.Length; row++)
        {
            List<string> cells = Regex.Matches(Regex.Replace(str[row], "<br>", ""), @"\<td.*?\</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
            //List<Tag> cells_tag = new List<Tag>();
            DataRow dtrow = output.NewRow();
            for (int column = 0; column < cells.Count/*cols.Length*/; column++)
            {
                Tag tdcell = new Tag();/*
                if ((prev_cell.Count > 0) &&prev_cell[row - 4][column].Attributes.ContainsKey("rowspan") && (Convert.ToInt32(prev_cell[row - 4][column].Attributes["rowspan"]) > 0))
                {
                    prev_cell[row - 4][column].Attributes["rowspan"] = (Convert.ToInt32(prev_cell[row - 4][column].Attributes["rowspan"]) - 1).ToString();
                    tdcell = prev_cell[row - 4][column];
                    cells.Insert(column, maketag(prev_cell[row - 4][column]));
                }
                else
                {*/
                    tdcell = tdparse(cells[column]);
                //}
                                 
                dtrow[column] = tdcell.Value;
                //cells_tag.Add(tdcell);
            }
            output.Rows.Add(dtrow);

            //prev_cell.Add(cells_tag);
        }
        return output;
    }

    #region Private Methods
    private string OnlyTable(string input, string tag)
    {
        string opentag = "<" + tag + " ";
        string closetag = "</" + tag + ">";
        string output = string.Empty;
        string[] temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input, opentag);
        foreach (string s in temp)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            if (s.Contains(closetag)) 
            {
                str = opentag + s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(closetag)) + closetag;
            }
            if (str.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                output = output + str.Trim();
            }
        }
        output = output.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
        return output;
    }

    private string RemoveHTMLComments(string input)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        string[] temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input, "<!--");
        foreach (string s in temp)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            if (!s.Contains("-->"))
            {
                str = s;
            }
            else
            {
                str = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("-->") + 3);
            }
            if (str.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                output = output + str.Trim();
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    private Tag tdparse(string input)
    {
        Tag output = new Tag() { Name = "td" };
        output.Value = GetValueOfTag(input, output.Name);
        output.Attributes = GetAttributesOfTag(input, output.Name);
        return output;
    }

    private string maketag(Tag input)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        string attributes = string.Empty;
        foreach (var attr in input.Attributes)
        {
            attributes += attr.Key + "=" + attr.Value + " ";
        }
        output = "<" + input.Name + " " + attributes + ">" + input.Value + "</" + input.Name + ">";
        return output;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetAttributesOfTag(string TagStr, string TagName)
    {
        var output = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string cell = Regex.Matches(TagStr, @"\<" + TagName + @".*?\>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()[0];
        cell = Regex.Replace(cell,@"\<"+TagName,""); cell = Regex.Replace(cell, @"\>", "");
        string s = cell.Substring(0, cell.IndexOf(@"='") + 2) + Regex.Replace(cell.Substring(cell.IndexOf(@"='") + 2, cell.Length - (cell.IndexOf(@"='") + 2))," ","");
        string[] ss = s.Split(' ');
        foreach(var item in ss)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) continue;
            output.Add(item.Split('=')[0], item.Split('=')[1]);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private string GetValueOfTag(string TagStr,string TagName)
    {
        string output = "";
        string value = Regex.Replace(TagStr, @"\<" + TagName + @".*?\>", "");
        output = Regex.Replace(value, @"\</" + TagName + @"\>", "");
        return output;
    }
    #endregion
}
class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Attributes { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данный баг.

P.S.: Знаю про сторонние библиотеки, так что не предлагать.

Comment: может в эту сторону копать https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47yh29a9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NMD, таблицу получить я получил, я не могу правильно допилить логику с rowspan, чтоб он не перемещал ячейки таблицы.

Comment: пример строки покажи, который вызывает трудности

Comment: @NMD, Если в коде то функция GetDataTable(string input), если ты про таблицу которую надо распарсить, то 28

Comment: Может уже и не надо, но заметил одну штуку в сорцах страницы и попробывал загрузить страницу в Excel и о чудо, она открылась и не надо заморачиваться с парсингом. В общем думаю, как прочитать xls файл в C#, вы сами найдете.

Comment: что за переменные columnsbyrow и tablefromrow, они ни где не объявлены!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NMD, спасибо большое за помощь, но я его сделал. Помучался и сделал:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string input)
{
    string[] tablerows = Regex.Matches(input, @"\<tr.*?\</tr>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
    string[] cols = Regex.Matches(tablerows[columnsbyrow], @"\<td.*?\</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
    DataTable output = new DataTable("Parsed Table");
    foreach (var col in cols)
    {
        output.Columns.Add(Regex.Replace(col, "<.*?>", String.Empty));
    }
    List<List<Tag>> LastRowspanRow = new List<List<Tag>>();
    for (int row = tablefromrow; row < tablerows.Length; row++)
    {
        List<string> cells = Regex.Matches(Regex.Replace(tablerows[row], "<br>", ""), @"\<td.*?\</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
        DataRow dtrow = output.NewRow();
        List<Tag> RowspanCell = new List<Tag>();
        for (int column = 0; column < cols.Length; column++)
        {
            Tag tdcell = new Tag();
            tdcell = tdparse(cells[column]);
            var lrsDict = (LastRowspanRow.Count > 0) ? LastRowspanRow[LastRowspanRow.Count - 1][column].Attributes : null;
            if (LastRowspanRow.Count > 0 && (lrsDict.ContainsKey("rowspan")) && (Convert.ToInt32(lrsDict["rowspan"]) > 1)) 
            {
                RowspanCell.Add(LastRowspanRow[LastRowspanRow.Count - 1][column]);
                RowspanCell[column].Attributes["rowspan"] = (Convert.ToInt32(lrsDict["rowspan"]) - 1).ToString();
                tdcell.Attributes["rowspan"] = RowspanCell[column].Attributes["rowspan"];

                cells.Insert(column, maketag(LastRowspanRow[LastRowspanRow.Count - 1][column]));
                dtrow[column] = "";                        
            }
            else
            {
                dtrow[column] = tdcell.Value;
                RowspanCell.Add(tdcell);
            }
        }
        LastRowspanRow.Add(RowspanCell);
        output.Rows.Add(dtrow);
    }
    return output;
}
```

вдруг кому пригодится: поменять надо только указанный метод и будет табличка :)